# could someone give an example to illustrate some kind of numerical errors caused by small variance in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

"[sklearn/naive_bayes](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0eebade2642b7f6c5105538eedada5b731998cc2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L364).py" says

> ```
>     # If the ratio of data variance between dimensions is too small, it
>     # will cause numerical errors. To address this, we artificially
>     # boost the variance by epsilon, a small fraction of the standard
>     # deviation of the largest dimension.
> ```

could someone give an example to illustrate this kind of numerical errors caused by small variance?

Answer (score 1):

Naive Bayes works with probabilities. Probabilities are often small numbers. To calculate joint probabilities, you need to multiply probabilities together. When you multiply one small number by another small number, you get a very small number (sometimes even doesn't fit in a 32-bit float value and a non-zero value becomes 0).

Sometimes, the variance of certain features is 0 which leads to a div by zero issue and numerical instability.